# Can an answer just ask questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I have posted an answer to this question: [No qualifying bean of type 'com.atlassian.velocity.VelocityManager' available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320461/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-com-atlassian-velocity-velocitymanager-available)

My answer does not answer the question, it just gives the OP some confidence that there is an answer, and asks for more information.

Perhaps I should have put that in a comment instead of an answer, but the lack of formatting in a. comment would have made it pretty unpleasant to read.

In short: is it ok to post a non-answer answer if your intention is to develop it into a solution as more information is given by the OP?

Comment: Interesting to know that happens but I hope I'm not quite that evil :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> is it ok to post a non-answer answer

No.

Intention does not matter. All that matters is what you post. If it's not an answer, then don't post it as one.

If you have questions, ask them in comments, chat, smoke signals, or whatever you prefer. If/when the information is provided, you can go ahead and answer the question.

---

*That said*, I don't think what you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408377) is problematic. Your conclusion is:

> what you are seeing shouldn't happen.

…which counts as an answer: "no repro". As long as you are posting an answer, then it's OK, even if you later have to go back and change the verdict based on new information (but we'd rather *not* do that—if information is missing, we'd prefer to close the question, not post speculative answers).

Comment: Thanks, that makes things clearer. I hope they come back with enough info for me to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: **"which counts as an answer: "no repro""** ... I hope the communities opinion on that will remain different [Are "Your code works fine for me" answers acceptable?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277923)

Comment: @Tom Uh... since forever. Servy's answer there is wrong, in the sense that it does not represent site policy and never has. See George Stocker's comment there. There are multiple other Q&A here on Meta that establish the opposite ruling.

Comment: I've removed that "since" part from my comment, that was misleading, yes. That Stack Overflow has broad and lenient rules on answers to counter their own agenda of being a repository of quality questions and answers is not new, so I just kept my hope (in the above comment) that the community will persist on a different opinion there and use their votes appropriately.

Comment: @Tom This is not a quality issue. There's no quality gap with answers pointing out that the problem described in the question is not an actual problem.

Comment: The issue is with the whole Q&A. When OP failed to describe the issue appropriately, then the should be closed. Then someone answers with "I can't reproduce it" then this is not an answer to the question why something fails/doesn't work/whatever, it is merely pointing out that the question lacks information. That's what comments are for. But I don't want to misuse the comment section for a discussion, it isn't designed for that. Greetings.

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the OP failed to describe the issue appropriately.

Comment: *whatever you prefer* Interpretive dance! W00t! You should see my Dijkstra's Shortest Path set to Hotel California.